Docker container aspnet6 GCCLIB
I am trying to create a container base image. Mine is a DotNet6.0 Application which has few C++ related dependencies and code integrations.
I am using below base Image to build my app and it copies few libs, files that are part of the configuration which C++ files depends upon.  These files are Rhel9 based files.
Below is the base Image I am trying to use
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0

When I run my container I am seeing below issues.
./abcadsf.so: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.29' not found (required by /ab/sdk/mylibs/gcc1131/lib/abcadsf.so)

I tried apt-get to update the GLIB but I do not have sudo permissions since these are running in my org.
I assume this is because of the asp6.0 base image not have specific GCLIB Version.
is there any alternate base Image that I could use ?
Please suggest

If you set USER root in your Dockerfile you can do whatever you want.  Upgrading system libraries and especially libc can be tricky (if you get it wrong absolutely everything will stop working; it'll be isolated in a container here at least).  Can you use a newer base image instead?

Yes, Is there any newer base image that is based on dotnet6.0 with those libs ?
